# How to set max string length on my EditorGUI.TextArea?

Tags: unity

How to set max string length on a `EditorGUI.TextArea`? A `GUILayout.TextArea` has a `maxLength` property but sadly the editor-version doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a bit more tricky that I originally thought. Here is my test code :

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyWindow : EditorWindow {

   string textAreastring =" ";
    int stringLimit = 3;
   [MenuItem("Test/My Window")]
    static void Init()
    {

        // Get existing open window or if none, make a new one:
        MyWindow window = (MyWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(MyWindow));
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        textAreastring = EditorGUI.TextArea(new Rect(0, 0, 250, 25), textAreastring);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (textAreastring.Length >= stringLimit)
            {
                textAreastring = textAreastring.Substring(0, stringLimit);
                GUI.FocusControl(null);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see the trick is in the `EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();` and  if `(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())`. After we check for a change we can truncate the string anyway we want. Now the problem is this only takes affect when the window looses focus so this is why I put  `GUI.FocusControl(null);` at the end. Not the best solution by far but I can only come up with this on the fly. If anyone can figure out a better way please do!